# Laravel - create object with belongsTo relationship

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, relationship

I am using Laravel 5.2 and I have associated an usergroup to any user with a belongsTo relationship. Now I want to create users with the correct relationship. Is there any possibility to take the correct relationship into to create method?

For example, my current code updates the object after creation:

```
$usergroup = Usergroup::findOrFail($usergroupId);

$user = User::create([
        'email' => $request->email,
        'password' => bcrypt($request->password) ]);
$user->usergroup()->associate($usergroup);
$user->save();
```

It works, but it isn't a pretty solution. I tried some things but none worked. I want something like:

```
$usergroup = Usergroup::findOrFail($usergroupId);

$user = User::create([
        'email' => $request->email,
        'password' => bcrypt($request->password)
        'usergroup' => $usergroup ]); // does not work!
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, just save the related model's id to the foreign key field:

```
$user = User::create([
    'email' => $request->email,
    'password' => bcrypt($request->password),
    'usergroup_id' => $usergroupId // or whatever it is
]);
```

Comment: No, that does not work. The attribute and value are correct but it doesn't get saved in the database.

Comment: Are the proper attributes unguarded?

Comment: Okay, I didn't know that I had to add 'usergroup_id' to the $fillable array of my model. Thank you!